# Scale parameter of GetMap function within RgoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, r

Within the R library called "RgoogleMaps", there is a function called "GetMap" which is used to save a georeferenced image file. The library's [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RgoogleMaps/RgoogleMaps.pdf) suggest that the SCALE parameter supposed to be used to obtain high-quality (i.e. high spatial resolution) images. However, regardless the value I use for the SCALE parameter the size of the spatial resolution, hence the size of the image, does not change.

Sample R code to obtain the map centered at the given lat-lon coordinates with a SCALE value of 20 is as follows:

```
lat = 39.864849;
lon = 32.733805;
center = c(lat, lon);
MyMap <- GetMap(center, size=c(640,640), destfile="HU_Test.png", zoom = 12, maptype="satellite", RETURNIMAGE = TRUE, GRAYSCALE = FALSE, NEWMAP = TRUE, SCALE = 20, verbose = 1);
```

Can you could help me obtain high-quality georeferenced images by using the GetMap function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Google maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#scale_values): `"Default scale value is 1; accepted values are 1, 2, and (for Maps API for Business customers only) 4"`.
If I set SCALE = 2, I do get a hi-res image.